# Filling the gap in my understanding

Tags: function

I was going through the following series of lecture notes on OS :

http://williamstallings.com/Extras/OS-Notes/h3.html

Here while trying to explain the different outcomes the program for thread can produce it breaks down the execution of function and says the following line :

"sum first reads the value of a into a register. It then increments the register, then stores the contents of the register back into a. It then reads the values of of the control string, p and a into the registers that it uses to pass arguments to the printf routine. It then calls printf, which prints out the data"

I exactly don't know how a function is executed at the level of registers and at the same time don't know which topic should I learn to know more about it .

So , which topic encompasses this execution of function at the level of registers and the level of electronic circuits?
please kindly elaborate how a stack is incremented while a value is being read during the execution of function .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice to look at the assambler code is already a good one. You can look up the assembler instructions and think what happens if at any instruction the thread execution changes to the other thread.

Look at this code

```
la      a, %r0
ld      [%r0],%r1
add     %r1,1,%r1
st      %r1,[%r0]

ld      [%r0], %o3 ! parameters are passed starting with %o0
mov     %o0, %o1
la      .L17, %o0
call    printf
```

In the first four lines (the a++) there are different possibilities how the execution can happen. You dont know if sum(1) or sum(0) is called first.

To understand what is ongoing on a deeper level I suggest you look up 'computer organization'. See for example this link [Computer Organisation WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/IB/Group_4/Computer_Science/Computer_Organisation).

Comment: Fox : Thanks a lot . I am unable to see as to how there are different possibilities as to how execution should happen .

Comment: Fox : Which processor has been used , I mean the mnemonics are different for different processors ,right ?

Comment: Doesn't it seem like sum(1) is being called first in the code ?

Comment: The problem is it is executed by a thread. So you don't know if the scheduler switches immediately to the new thread or if the main thread of your program is executed before the scheduler switches. There is no way to say if the thread t or the main thread is executed first and it may be different each time you execute the program.

Comment: Maybe it is the gcc assembler. You can try to generate assembler on a Unix/Linux system with 'gcc file.c -S -o file.S' which should generate an assembly file with a .S ending like the author in your link states 'It will put the generated assembly in the same file name as the .c or .cc file, but with a .s suffix.'.

Comment: Fox : Oh !!!.. I thought thread is a construct that we create using classes,objects and all...So , thread is a keyword right ? And writing that keyword lets us create a thread during run-time . Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. In the code example a thread is created. And also look up what fork does (here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html). And I would be glad if you accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: If the user doesn't create a thread by his code ,even then also the processor will create a thread ,right ? And Fork seems to be an inbuilt function ,the programmer doesn't need to write the code to define the function ,right ?

Comment: Fork is a so called system call. Linux/Unix implements the system calls defined by the POSIX standard while windows implements similar functionality in the win32 api.